# How to separate effect from menulist and sub-menulist?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

I'm newbie and I use blogger template. my problem is in sub-menulist and sub-sub-menulist, I can not highlight second sub-sub-menu if there is othere one after it.

So any one can tell me how can I separate this effects between next sun-menu and next sub-sub-menu ?

this the code:

```
[<li><a href='#'>MENULIST</a>
<ul>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>SUB-MENULIST A</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>sub-sub-menulist 1</span></a></li>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>sub-sub-menulist 2</span></a></li>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>sub-sub-menulist 3</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>MENULIST B</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>sub-sub-menulist 1</span></a></li>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>sub-sub-menulist 2</span></a></li>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>sub-sub-menulist 3</span></a></li>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>sub-sub-menulist 4</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>MENULIST C</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>sub-sub-menulist 1</span></a></li>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>sub-sub-menulist 2</span></a></li>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>sub-sub-menulist 3</span></a></li>
<li><a class='trigger' href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>sub-sub-menulist 4</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### ][1]

```
#menu-main{display:none;}
#header {
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #222;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: none;
    width: 466px;
}
```

---

```
<!--Menu To Drop Down Started-->
<script type='text/javascript'> 
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
selectnav('menu-main', {
  label: 'Select Here ',
  nested: true,
  autoselect: false,
  indent: '-'
});
});
//]]></script>
<!--Menu To Drop Down End-->
```

---

I can't choose (sub-sub-menulist 2) because every time it shows (MENULIST B) automatically.

Comment: Could you please post a jsfiddle or something your code looks incomplete

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the CSS and JavaScript as well.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, This should be a comment rather.

Comment: thnk you sir, I just did